# Big Objects - How to Retry a Batch?

Tags: apex, batch, big-object

In exploring Big Objects the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_considerations.htm) state the below:

> When working with big data and writing batches of records using APIs
> or Apex, you can experience a partial batch failure while some records
> are written and others aren’t. Because the database is highly
> responsive and consistent at scale, this type of behavior is expected.
> In these cases, simply retry until all records are written.

So I am using a batch class and ultimately:

```
Database.SaveResult[] srList = database.insertImmediate(stuffIWant);
```

But if there is error in the saveresult list how I can re-add or retry that particular batch?

Thinking at the moment along the lines of storing in a list and firing the batch class again from the finish method.

Comment: Hello @Girbot, did you get the answer for this ?